# WCF Rest Service Call

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I am calling a rest service in ajax.
If I add the svc file in the same project and call I am able to call the url

The below is the URL working

```
http://localhost:1947/GreenViewService.svc/?callback
```

If I add the svc in separate project layer and call in ajax I am unable to call it says 403 forbidden error and sometimes 405 error.

If I call the below url from different layer not working is it because port no. varies. should I give any access rights.

```
function GetDataPoints() {
            alert('S');
            var action = 'http://localhost:1984/GreenViewService.svc/?callback=';
            alert(action);
            $.ajax({
                "type": "GET",
                "url": action,
                "cache": false,
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "text",
                "success": function(result) {
                alert(eval(result));
                    var json = eval(result);
                    //fillDropDown(json, prefix + 'DataPoint', 'NodeLabel', 'ID');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can't point you to the exact problem. But I've been working with rest services once before on an .net project. There I ran into the problem that I kept getting an 403. I used an libary I found, see https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib. It helped me providing the right access to my webservice.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it works when in the same project but not in a different project.

The difference is that when it is in a different project it is a cross site call.

To do a cross site call you need to use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/)